# Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)") on Azure Linux

Tags: python, sql-server, django, odbc, django-pyodbc-azure

I'm trying to deploy python django app on azure linux using azure cli and after deployment it is showing me database connectivity error for drivers.
The error message is:

> Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0
> (SQLDriverConnect)") on Azure Linux

[image]

Comment: Have you installed ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (for Linux)? Did you follow the instructions linked from [Creating REST API with Python, Django and Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-sql-db-django/azure-sql-db-django/) to configure Azure SQL connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

If you on Ubuntu you can folow this link it helped
[Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#17)